# Cookies doesn't appears in Chrome Console Resources tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, grails, cookies

I'am working an a `Grails` app and create different cookies.

Some appears in the chrome `console Resources TAB` and some are not showing.

I need to get the value of these Cookies using `Angularjs` and can access only the one that are showing on `console Resources TAB`.

The other cookies are visible in the Chrome `Content settings button`.
In the `Cookies section`, but not in the Chrome `console Resources TAB`.

All cookies are created the same way:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("username", username)
cookie.maxAge = 1209600 //14 days
cookie.httpOnly = true
response.addCookie(cookie)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok the problem was the path. To be visible in all the page the path must be `"/"`

```
cookie.setPath("/")
```

Comment: Still relevant in September of 2017!